# wp_query orderby title and meta key value (WP3.1)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query

I have a taxonomy wp_query and i would like to order the list by **title and** by **meta** value (numeric value)

- Have a meta value Interesting = 1 or 0 in the posts
- Not so interesting posts would be at the bottom of the query

**GOAL - OUTPUT LIKE THIS:** (is this possible with WP_QUERY and WP3.1)

**A** ( META KEY interesting = **1**)

**B** ( META KEY interesting = **1**)

**C** ( META KEY interesting = **1**)

**A** ( META KEY interesting = **0**)

**B** ( META KEY interesting = **0**)

Comment: as of WP 4.0+ see this: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the `orderby` part of the query to get what you want (trying to pass it via the `orderby` parameter will not work, it will be filtered out). This simple example adds the `meta_value` sort order before the standard title sort order.

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse15168_posts_orderby' );
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'interesting',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse15168_posts_orderby' );

function wpse15168_posts_orderby( $orderby )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value DESC, ' . $orderby;
    return $orderby;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code! Is it possible somehow to move `add_filter` to functions.php instead of having it in a template? I'm constructing `$args` array and passing it to `new WP_Query($args)`. In the functions.php I've added the filter and trying to test for my CPT as `get_query_var('post_type') == 'custom-post-type-name'`. But this fails. The reason I want to add the filter code to functions.php is because the `orderby` is the global thing throughout the website for my CPT and used in quite a few templates. Hope that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @DashaLuna: Moving it to `functions.php should be no problem. If you use a separate `WP_Query` you should probably not use `get_query_var()` since that will read the global `$wp_query` object, not your current custom query. Use the second parameter that is passed to the `posts_orderby` filter instead.

Comment: thank you very much! Yep, that was my mistake as the function was 'looking' at the global `$wp_query`, which was displaying a page. I've modifed the function that the `posts_orderby` filter calles to include 2nd query param as following: `properties_list_orderby( $orderby, $pqry )` and then I can test if my CPT is queried as following: `if( $pqry->query_vars['post_type'] == 'custom-post-type-name')`. Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this and trigger the ordering by URL?

Answer (score 1):

you can't mix ascending and descending order, but if you switch the zeroes and ones then this might work:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key => 'interesting',
                              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title',
                              'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Comment: You actually can mix ascending/descending... `'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'menu_order' => 'ASC' )` (per... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Yes @Stephanie you can do that since version 4.0. Back in 2011 when I wrote my answer that was not possible. Thank you for the update!