# Secondary Sort (fallback) for WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, order

What I'm after is creating a secondary (or default) `orderby` option for a custom query. Here is what I have:

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => $taxfunc_post_type,
    'meta_key'  => '_mouldings_dimensions_height',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'paged'     => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => $taxfunc_tax_name,
            'field'            => 'id',
            'include_children' => 0,
            'terms'            => $term_id
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'special_profile',
            'value' => $special_logic_serialized
        )
    )
);
```

What I'd like to do is if `_mouldings_dimensions_height` is `NULL`, then default back to `title`. I did see [Jan's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15629/9605) on this, which does appear to be related, but I think I'm after the opposite. Ideally, I'd also be checking for just this query with `query_var['post_type']` as the original questioner asked, but am not sure I am approaching this correctly. Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly apprecaited. Thanks!

*Update*
After a bit more testing, it appears to list the oldest first as a fallback when the meta value is the same across multiple posts (NULL in this case) -- looking to change this behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a quite simple revision to your current code. You can add multiple "orderby" values separated by a space.

```
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num title',
```

This should keep the priority of sorting by your meta value, with a secondary sort of title.

Comment: I sort on a custom field (a year) and I want to set up secondary sorting on the publish date. I tried `'orderby' => 'meta_value date'`, but the addition of `date` breaks the primary sort order. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Maybe post your query somewhere so we can take a look? It should by all means work..

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @Pieter refers. My query: ``'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num title', 'order' => 'DESC'``. The ``DESC`` won't apply when the ``title`` sorting attribute is added.

Comment: Aaccording to the examples in the Codex, it should work just fine. Try doing a parse_request hook and echoing out the SQL query itself. Maybe you will see where the issue lies! :)
[http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters]